# retrofit returning object params out of order, with @ sign and quotes

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit to send a call to an api to post an issue in a bug-tracker through my android app.  The API needs it formatted a specific way, so I created a custom object to pass as a parameter.  Unfortunately when I'm sending the request to the API its formatting it incorrectly.  It alphabetizes the parameters, puts quotes around both the keys and the values, and adds an @ to the beginning of my data, leading the API to not be able to make sense of what I'm trying to post.  The format I'm looking to send is:

```
{ fb_user_id: dummyUID, 
email: dummy@email.com, 
first_name: John, 
last_name: Smith, 
project: android, 
type: bug, 
subject: title, 
description: description }
```

Instead of the above, my api is receiving the data as

```
@"description":"description",
"email":"dummy@email.com",
"fb_user_id":"dummyUID",
"first_name":"John",
"last_name":"Smith",
"project":"android",
"subject":"title",
"type":"bug"
```

I'm using retrofit to do so, with my interface looking like

```
public interface MyAPI {
@POST("/op_create_ticket")
Observable<JsonElement> createTicket(@Body Ticket ticket);
}
```

And my activity calling it looking like:

```
public class HelpActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.textView)
    TextView textView;
    @BindView(R.id.spinner)
    Spinner spinner;
    @BindView(R.id.email)
    EditText email;
    @BindView(R.id.firstName)
    EditText firstName;
    @BindView(R.id.lastName)
    EditText lastName;
    @BindView(R.id.subject)
    EditText title;
    @BindView(R.id.description)
    EditText description;
    @BindView(R.id.button3)
    Button button3;

    FirebaseAuth fbauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = fbauth.getCurrentUser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button3)
    public void onViewClicked() {
        final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
        builder.baseUrl("https://my.url");
        builder.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create());
        builder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        MyAPI api = retrofit.create(TriggerWatchAPI.class);

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.setFb_user_id(user.getUid());
        ticket.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
        ticket.setFirst_name(firstName.getText().toString());
        ticket.setLast_name(lastName.getText().toString());
        ticket.setProject("android");
        ticket.setType("design");
        ticket.setSubject(title.getText().toString());
        ticket.setDescription(description.getText().toString());

        api.createTicket(ticket).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(JsonElement jsonElement) {
                        Log.d(getTag(), "zzzOnNext");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(getTag(), "err", e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any kind of converter or something that can convert my object to the kind of data the API is looking for.

edit: forgot to add my custom pojo

```
package watch.trigger.Model;

public class Ticket {

        private String project;

        private String first_name;

        private String email;

        private String description;

        private String subject;

        private String last_name;

        private String fb_user_id;

        private String type;

        public String getProject ()
        {
            return project;
        }

        public void setProject (String project)
        {
            this.project = project;
        }

        public String getFirst_name ()
        {
            return first_name;
        }

        public void setFirst_name (String first_name)
        {
            this.first_name = first_name;
        }

        public String getEmail ()
        {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail (String email)
        {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getDescription ()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription (String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getSubject ()
        {
            return subject;
        }

        public void setSubject (String subject)
        {
            this.subject = subject;
        }

        public String getLast_name ()
        {
            return last_name;
        }

        public void setLast_name (String last_name)
        {
            this.last_name = last_name;
        }

        public String getFb_user_id ()
        {
            return fb_user_id;
        }

        public void setFb_user_id (String fb_user_id)
        {
            this.fb_user_id = fb_user_id;
        }

        public String getType ()
        {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType (String type)
        {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "ClassPojo [project = "+project+", first_name = "+first_name+", email = "+email+", description = "+description+", subject = "+subject+", last_name = "+last_name+", fb_user_id = "+fb_user_id+", type = "+type+"]";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, add code of Ticket.class

Comment: just realized that was missing

Comment: Can you add retrofit logs?

Comment: Not familiar with retrofit, but the API is expecting JSON? Is there a header or annotation to set to tell it to send JSON?

Comment: is it actually json if it doesn't use the quotes?  i thought json would have the quotes

Answer (score 0):

don't send a custom object, send a JSON object as a String and in the API receive it as a JSON object.

first add this in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
```

1- change this

```
public interface MyAPI {

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/op_create_ticket")
Observable<JsonElement> createTicket(@Body Ticket ticket);
}
```

to :

```
public interface MyAPI {
@POST("/op_create_ticket")
Observable<String> createTicket(@Body String ticket);
}
```

2- change this

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setFb_user_id(user.getUid());
    ticket.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    ticket.setFirst_name(firstName.getText().toString());
    ticket.setLast_name(lastName.getText().toString());
    ticket.setProject("android");
    ticket.setType("design");
    ticket.setSubject(title.getText().toString());
    ticket.setDescription(description.getText().toString());

    api.createTicket(ticket).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<JsonElement>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(JsonElement jsonElement) {
                    Log.d(getTag(), "zzzOnNext");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(getTag(), "err", e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

to

```
  JSONObject tickenJson= new JSONObject();

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.setFb_user_id(user.getUid());
        ticket.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
        ticket.setFirst_name(firstName.getText().toString());
        ticket.setLast_name(lastName.getText().toString());
        ticket.setProject("android");
        ticket.setType("design");
        ticket.setSubject(title.getText().toString());
        ticket.setDescription(description.getText().toString());

ticketJson.put("fb_user_id",user.getUid());
ticketJson.put("email",email.getText().toString());
ticketJson.put("first_name",firstName.getText().toString());
ticketJson.put("last_name",lastName.getText().toString());
ticketJson.put("project","android");
ticketJson.put("type","design");
ticketJson.put("type",title.getText().toString());
ticketJson.put("description",description.getText().toString());
     api.createTicket(ticketJson.toString()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(JsonElement jsonElement) {
                        Log.d(getTag(), "zzzOnNext");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(getTag(), "err", e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: JsonObject.put doesn't appear to be a valid method.  Could you mean ticketJson.addProperty?

Comment: there are two classes for JSON in android.
yes, ticketJson.addProperty  equal ticketJson.put

Comment: The response i get after that is


Data: "@\"fb_user_id\":\"CSLbKEtCMqf4py73Gih2udifxq73\",\"email\":\"test@email.com\",\"first_name\":\"First \",\"last_name\":\"Last\",\"project\":\"design\",\"subject\":\"Demo\",\"description\":\"Dummy text\""

Comment: please use "JSONObject " it's another class for JSON. see the answer update

Comment: Don't forget to add header

Comment: changed it from JsonObject to JSONObject, addproperty to put, added a header of     @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Cache-Control: max-age=640000"})
to before the retrofit method, and got the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182620/discussion-between-paxana-non-grata-and-momen-zaqout).